# Код бота не вызывает функцию

Tags: python, aiogram

Бот управляет двумя таблицами: users и bans. При получении комментария в чате, бот записывает id комментатора в таблицу users и проверяет наличие id комментатора в таблице bans. Если id есть в таблице bans, то бот должен удалить любой комментарий забаненного.
Но не удаляет и не могу понять почему. Как исправить ошибку?

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def check_database(message: types.Message):
    if not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
        print(message.from_user.id, 1) #выводит id комментатора
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id, message.from_user.first_name)
        await check_bans(message)
        print(message.from_user.id, 2) #выводит id комментатора
        await mess_handler(message)
        print(message.from_user.id, 3) #выводит id комментатора

async def check_bans(message: types.Message):
    print(message.from_user.id, 4) #выводит id комментатора
    if db.user_bans(message.from_user.id):
        print(message.from_user.id, 5) #ничего не выводит
        await message.delete()
        print(message.from_user.id, 6) #ничего не выводит

async def mess_handler(message: types.Message):
    text = message.text.lower()
    print(message.from_user.id, 7) #выводит id комментатора
    if str(message.from_user.id) != cfg.ADMIN_ID:
        for word in cfg.WORDS:
            if word in text:
                await message.delete()
```

Очередность принтов в консоли:
1
4
2
7
3

Код файла db:

```
class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))

    def user_bans(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result1 = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'bans' WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
class Database:

    # ...

    def user_bans(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'bans' WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_id,))
            return bool(self.cursor.fetchone())
    
    # ...
```

Comment: Все равно не работает

Comment: Можете добавить больше принтов? Чтоб было понятно, какой код вызывается, а какой нет.

Comment: Не совсем знаком с этим, что указать в качестве аргумента?

Comment: Функцию `print()` засуньте буквально на каждой строке кода. Во внутрь передавайте хоть числа - и записывайте. `1` принутется когда бот готов, `8` - когда клиент пишет сообщения, `13` - когда выполняется проверка в БД. И посмотрите, какие цифры у вас есть, а каких нет. Кстати, возможно проблема в том, что вы не коммитите добавление забанненых.

Comment: Принты id выводит на первой и третьей функции, они и работают. А вот вторую функцию "перерпрыгивает" и принты не выводятся

Comment: То есть принт перед бансом работает, и принт после вызова, а принт в самом начале (ещё до кода) внутри банса не работает?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Обновите вопрос. Добавьте туда код с дебагом, и порядок действий + консоль.

Comment: К сожалению, пока не умею пользоваться дебагом, не понимаю сообщения в дебагере

Comment: Зачем дебагер? Просто сделайте принты в каждой строке.

Comment: Сделал. У меня в таблице users и bans уже есть один комментатор, на нем и тестирую. Вторую функцию вообще не видит, перескакивает на третью.

Comment: Добавил принтов, теперь еще больше неясности с переменными

Comment: Если вы переделали код на аналогичный тому, что я предложил - значит просто нет пользователя в базе данных. Рекомендую проверить.

Comment: P. S. Стоп. Возможно ошибка в том, что вы имя таблицы в `'` указываете. Имя таблицы всегда объект имени, а не строка. Попробуйте убрать.

Comment: И то же самое со всеми наименованиями.

Comment: Не знаю, что делать - код не работает. В обеих таблицах есть тестовая запись, второй блок кода просто не работает и игнорируется. В чем ошибка не понимаю.